# How can I run an application that depends on a SQL database on another machine with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, crud

I have created a CRUD application that is running really well. It connects to SQL on the same machine. I want to publish my C# app and install it on another PC does not have SQL.

Is it possible to run it on that PC, without installing SQL Server on it? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: not complete sure but you mave have a look at the SQL LocalDb afaik this does not need a installation https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/Hh510202(v=SQL.120).aspx

Comment: @BoasEnkler: SQL Server LocalDB ***does*** in fact need to be installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to run it on that PC?

Without a database your application is "dead".

You have two options.

- Install a sql server it this PC.
- Connect to a sql server isntalled in another PC.

It's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a small one and the database is less than 4GB and you are not going to install SQL Server on every machine and your client do not have access to a Server with SQL Server then you may want to use [SQL Server compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

In this case your database would be an single `sdf` file and you will connect to it using its path on the machine. Then the connection string would be like this:

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Max Database Size=256;Persist Security Info=False;
```

For more on connection string see [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/).

Here is the [download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)